# Ignoring zero when calculating MIN MAX for time spans

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help! I am trying to calculate time periods within a shift worked using the MIN MAX function and I cannot ignore the zero when a shift is not worked.. Below is the shift times and the "service hours" in the shift:

```
Start   Finish  Hours   Service Hrs
11:00   16:00   5.00    4.00
```

For the service hours calculation I use:

```
=(MIN(C1,D5)-MAX(B1,C5))*24
```

But when a shift isn't worked, the service hours still equal 4.00.

How do I ignore this?

Comment: Will you provide more details like: value of C1 and B1, and what D5 and C5 Referring?

Comment: I use C1 and B1 as the time bands that the MIN and MAX times are calculated. Service hours can only be between 11:00 and 15:00 and all time outside of this band is ignored.

Comment: C5 and D5 are the start and finish times

Comment: You can change your formula as `=(MIN($C$1,D5)- IF(C5=0, 0, MAX($B$1,C5 )))*24`, For Ignoring Zero, if Start and Finish Time is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would test specifically that both a start and end time have been entered before allowing the formula to do anything, something like:

```
=IF(COUNT(C5:D5)=2, (MIN(C1,D5)-MAX(B1,C5))*24, "")
```